# PDF.js viewer pinch to zoom

Tags: javascript, android, ios, pdf, pdf.js

I'm using [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) for rendering my documents on a web app I'm working on.

However I need to enable pinch to zoom on mobile devices for this and it doesn't look like the library itself allows native zooming.

Is there a library that I could use to the code to simulate (at the very least) pinch and zoom on the same scale as the viewers dropdown zoom selection?

Comment: There is some work done towards SVG backend for PDF.js, see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/svgviewer -- you might be interested in that instead of generic viewer.

Comment: Whats the performance like on this.  The current viewer that I have just destroys the memory usage (In safari debug mode I had it at 100mb-200mb when scrolling zoomed in).


I also managed to get touch events working using the Hammer.js library.  However, now when i zoom in past 110% on a  mobile device it destroys the text in the pdf (leaves only white pages and blue borders where links used to be)

Comment: What version of pdf.js are you using? Have you taken a look at the 'USE_ONLY_CSS_ZOOM' option? See: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/2439 and https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/4834

Answer (score 4):

I had found an answer to this solution.  I ended up using hammer.js for the pdf.js

http://hammerjs.github.io/

edit

```
var mc = new Hammer.Manager(myElement, myOptions);

mc.add( new Hammer.Pan({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL, threshold: 0 }) );
mc.add( new Hammer.Tap({ event: 'quadrupletap', taps: 4 }) );

mc.on("pan", handlePan);
mc.on("quadrupletap", handleTaps);
```

Comment: Here is the link to hammer.js: http://hammerjs.github.io/ (which btw I was not allowed to add to this answer :-/ - so maybe do it yourself, @Jordan)

Comment: @PhilLab Added the link to the answer.

Comment: Jordan, it will be better if you add the code which you wrote to do the pinch zoom. or atleast the skeleton code. Thanks.

Comment: Added boilerplate code for @Mr_Green.  I had used the code from their documentation.

Comment: @Jordan would be cool if you can also add the code for `handlePan` and `handleTaps` :-)

Comment: I also think that you should add a complete working code ;)

Comment: And then raise an invoice as well :/